# Is there a list of ALL standard commands of LaTeX 2e?

Tags: macros, arguments

I am looking for a list of all commands available in LaTeX 2e, commands available without packages. I am creating a parser for latex therefore I need to know all commands and the corresponding arguments. For instance:

```
\newcommand{name}[num]{definition}
```

I searched for a long time and didn't find such a list.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This is non-trivial.  Some commands define other commands, etc., perhaps depending on arguments passed to them.  I think the short answer is: no.

Comment: The LaTeX manual, ISBN 978-0201529838; The LaTeX Companion, ISBN 978-0201362992.

Comment: You can start with the [documented source `source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) of LaTeX and the [source itself `latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co). Both come in handy to learn LaTeX's inner workings. But there are lots of commands that define other commands, and there are TeX primitives, so Andrew's answer sums the situation pretty well...